# How to compare the first letters of a strings in R

Tags: r, compare, letters, letter

I need compare a vector with strings which in any case they have the same two first letters. How I do it? I know the function compare in the library compare but I don't get it to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you want to use `substr()`.  Otherwise, pleas give an example of the data you have and the answer you want.

Comment: Thank you so much. I already got do with the function `grep()` but I going to try with `substr()`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using strsplit. You can probably create a function using the approach.

```
s1 = "Cat"
s2 = "Cator"


s1.letter = strsplit(s1, split = "")[[1]]
s2.letter = strsplit(s2, split= "") [[1]]

sum(s1.letter[1:2] == s2.letter[1:2])==2
```

That would return True in this case